# ArcGIS Reference Layer over ArcGIS Terrain base(or Imagery) Layer using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api

I am using Openlayers for a Map application which uses basemaps by ESRI (or ArcGIS). What I am trying to achieve is something like this:
http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html
From Basemaps select Terrain with labels.

Here is what I am doing:

```
arcgis_world_ref_overlay   = new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGIS93Rest( "World Overlay Reference",
                                   "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Reference/World_Reference_Overlay/MapServer/export",
                                    {layers: "1",TRANSPARENT: true},{isBaseLayer: false,opacity: 0.5, displayInLayerSwitcher: false, visibility: false});

arcgis_terrain  = new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGIS93Rest("World Terrain Base", // name for display in LayerSwitcher
        "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Terrain_Base/MapServer/export", // service endpoint
        {layers: "0", format: 'PNG24', sphericalMercator: true});
```

Attached is the output I am getting:
[image]

This is the desired output (uses Dojo and cached tiles but same service):
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, and the OP might no longer be interested in the Answer, but I have found out the cause of the problem.

ArcGIS Online's reference map (http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Reference/World_Reference_Overlay/MapServer/) does not give the same output as a tiled map service, and a Dynamic Mapservice.

When you are using it in ESRI's webviewer, it is called as a Tiled Map service, and we get the expected output. When you are calling it in OpenLayers, or in ArcGIS JSAPI as a dynamic mapservice, the output from the server itself is very different. Hence you see the strange output that the OP has pointed out.